# Creating a link using laravel routes and vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

On my laravel home page I have a vue component like this

```
<new-tutor area-id="{{ $area->slug }}" tutor-id="{{ $tutor->slug }}" route="{{ route('tutor.show', [$area, $tutor]) }}"></new-tutor>
```

it returns all new tutors in a given area in individual bootstrap cards, and uses this controller

```
public function index(Request $request, Area $area, Profile $profile, Tutor $tutor)
    {

        $newTutors = Tutor::with(['user', 'area'])->inArea($area)->latestfirst()->get();



        return response()->json($newTutor, 200);
    }
```

I would like to be able to click on the tutors name and be sent to that tutors page, but I can't seem to get the tutor slug to pass though properly, and I am not sure why.

In my vue component I set the link like

```
<a :href="route">{{newTutor.name}}</a>
```

and I have props set up like this

```
props: {
  areaId: null,
  tutorId: null,
  route: { type: String, required: true }

},
```

the slug does come through in a dd on newTutors, and Tutor.

Also note, I am using the same web route

> tutor.show

in other blade templates, so I am mostly confident that that is not where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

if you using laravel + vuejs,You need add @{{}}

```html
<a :href="route">@{{newTutor.name}}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I managed to get it working using late that night using,

"<a :href="'/' + newTutor.area.slug + '/' + newTutor.slug">{{newTutor.name}}</a>"

Is there a difference between the two, or a reason why I should use one way over another? Or does it really matter?

Comment: You can also do it like this, `<a :href=``/${newTutor.area.slug}/${newTutor.slug}``>`